# How to mark custom pages to be removed in a Wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

we do a plugin and in this plugin we create some pages in the code. We would like to mark those pages to remove them in the future but not the others. Put a tag or something to find them. In our pages we just have one or several shortcode. We also want to identify the menus that we created in the plugin. We use "wp_insert_post($page);" to create the pages and "wp_delete_post" to remove them.

Comment: Just Add Unique #tag to your Pages. Thats it you can find it in future easily.

Comment: in the page near the [shortcode] ?

Comment: Your Question is not clear? Please elaborate is or give us a screenshot of current state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages and menus are equivalent `post` items in WordPress system. So I suggest you treat them the same way.

One solution I’d consider would be to add a custom meta on those posts, using `add_post_meta($post_id, '_to_be_removed', true, true)`.

To retreive and delete these, you’d use something like this:

```
global $wpdb;

// get the post ids
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_to_be_removed'");

// delete the retrieved posts
foreach ($post_ids as $post_id) {
    wp_delete_post($post_id);
}
```

You could also add a unique identifier in your `meta_key` name to prevent any colision with other plugins or theme, like simply prepending it with your plugin’s name.